# How to get extract dictionary embedded in a <script>

Tags: python, html, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the zip codes:shipping pairs from a portion of text within a  within a div.

I've tried to use .find to get the div and then .find again to get the  followed by a pattern to pass for the portion of the text I'd like the extraction to start from.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import json

my_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Prime-FREE-Same-Day-Delivery/b?ie=UTF8&node=8729023011'

divcontainer = page_soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'top'})

script = divcontainer.find("script").text

pattern = re.compile(r'postalToProgramIDHash \"(.*?)\"', re.MULTILINE)

zips = re.search(pattern, script)
```

portion of script I want to extract:

```
 'postalToProgramIdHash':  {"94087":"free_same_day","11412":"free_same_day","93227":"free_same_day","75227":"free_same_day"..."84130":"free_same_day","40233":"free_same_day","27717":"free_same_day","45202":"free_same_day"},
    'marketplaceId'
```

I expect a dictionary with zip code:shipping key:value pairs as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pattern `re.compile(r"'postalToProgramIdHash':\s*({.*?})", flags=re.MULTILINE)`

**Ex:**

```
import re
import json

script = """'postalToProgramIdHash':  {"94087":"free_same_day","11412":"free_same_day","93227":"free_same_day","75227":"free_same_day", "84130":"free_same_day","40233":"free_same_day","27717":"free_same_day","45202":"free_same_day"},
    'marketplaceId'"""

pattern = re.compile(r"'postalToProgramIdHash':\s*({.*?})", flags=re.MULTILINE)

zips = re.search(pattern, script)
print(json.loads(zips.group(1)))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'11412': u'free_same_day',
 u'27717': u'free_same_day',
 u'40233': u'free_same_day',
 u'45202': u'free_same_day',
 u'75227': u'free_same_day',
 u'84130': u'free_same_day',
 u'93227': u'free_same_day',
 u'94087': u'free_same_day'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach - no regex!

```
to_dict = script.replace('{','}').replace('"','').split('}')
final = dict(item.split(":") for item in to_dict[1].split(","))
print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'94087': 'free_same_day', '11412': 'free_same_day', '93227': 'free_same_day', '75227': 'free_same_day', ' 84130': 'free_same_day', '40233': 'free_same_day', '27717': 'free_same_day','45202': 'free_same_day'}
```